# What are methods for validating complex SQL on petabyte scale data?

Tags: sql, validation, hive, data-processing

I'm writing a rather lengthy SQL script, implementing [Slowly Changing Dimensions (Type 2)](https://www.nuwavesolutions.com/slowly-changing-dimensions/), among other business logic. It runs on petabyte-sized data in Apache Hive.

Since it's tracking changes over time, I'm getting stumped at the best way to validate that this process works properly. If it were smaller data, I'd be able to get somewhat of a sense of accuracy based on row-size, growth rate, and looking more closely at the outcome rows. However that's not practical with such large data. In theory I also could pick out a handful of IDs and spot check, but it's likely that this would miss edge cases or less obvious bugs.

What are methods I can use to test my SQL code in a more robust way, despite the size? Is there a concept of writing unit tests for SQL (and if so, what would that even look like)?